# How to pass variables across thread groups in JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

Been trying to extract a value from the response data of a thread group,store it in a variable use the variable in the subsequent thread group. Would be great if someone provides insights on how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are local to a thread. Use properties as they're common to all threads.

From [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

Answer (score 0):

- Use [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function to convert JMeter Variable to JMeter Property in one thread group
- Use  [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function to access previously set property value in another thread group(s)

See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for detailed explanation